# Python Merge Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I wish to merge to two dataframes Df1 and Df2

```
import pandas as pd

    Df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'name' : ['jack', None, None],
        'Surname' : ['Peterson', 'Macleans', None],
        'city' : ['Sydney', 'Delhi', 'New york']})
```

,

```
Df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'name' : ['jack', 'Riti', 'Aadi','Jeff'],
        'Surname' : ['Peterson', 'Macleans', 'McDonald','Cooper'],
        'city' : ['Sydney', 'Delhi', 'New york','Tokyo'],
        'Rating' : ['AAA', 'AA', 'A','BBB']})
```

I want Pandas to first merge based on the first column, and if the match fails, it merge them based on the second column and if it fails it merge them based on the third column.

I used

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame([])
new_df = pd.merge(Df1, Df2,  how='left', left_on=['name','Surname','city'], right_on = ['name','Surname','city'])
```

yet this does not generate my desire dataframe

```
Final_Df = pd.DataFrame({
        'name' : ['jack', None, None],
        'Surname' : ['Peterson', 'Macleans', None],
        'city' : ['Sydney', 'Delhi', 'New york'],
        'Rating' : ['AAA', 'AA', 'A']})
```

Edit 1:
Thank you "Quang Hoang" for providing the answer!

Let's try a `for` loop:

```
Df1['Rating']=np.nan

for col in Df1.columns[:-1]:
    Df1['Rating'] = Df1['Rating'].fillna(Df1[col].map(Df2.set_index(col)['Rating']))
```

Output:

```
   name   Surname      city Rating
0  jack  Peterson    Sydney    AAA
1  None  Macleans     Delhi     AA
2  None      None  New york      A
```

Edit 2:
In Case one has extra column in Df1, which is not in Df2, the correct code will look like this:

```
import numpy as np

Df1['Rating']=np.nan

for col in ['name', 'Surname','city']:
    Df1['Rating'] = Df1['Rating'].fillna(Df1[col].map(Df2.set_index(col)['Rating']))
```

Edit 3:
In Case of duplicates in Df1 columns, the following code did work.

```
import numpy as np

Df1['Rating']=np.nan

for col in ['name', 'Surname','city']:
    Df1['Rating'] = Df1['Rating'].fillna(Df1[col].map(Df2.drop_duplicates(col).set_index(col)['Rating']))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a `for` loop:

```
Df1['Rating']=np.nan

for col in Df1.columns[:-1]:
    Df1['Rating'] = Df1['Rating'].fillna(Df1[col].map(Df2.set_index(col)['Rating']))
```

Output:

```
   name   Surname      city Rating
0  jack  Peterson    Sydney    AAA
1  None  Macleans     Delhi     AA
2  None      None  New york      A
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day! Just a quick question, if say Df1 has a column that is not available in Df2, e.g. Occupation, then how can you make this code work?


`Df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name' : ['jack', None, None],
    'Surname' : ['Peterson', 'Macleans', None],
    'city' : ['Sydney', 'Delhi', 'New york'],
    'Occupation':['Teacher','Student', 'Professor']})`

Comment: `for col in list_col_to_map:...`?